# How to beat the 10 candy arcade game ("Super RPG")?

Tags: candy-box-2

I got as far as the 7th level then I die every time. How do you beat this game?

Comment: What equipment do you typically have at that point?  I just beat 8 but it takes a little luck; I have died on 7 a bunch.

Comment: Alright I found a way to make it to 8th consistently. The strategy is to upgrade max HP when you can instead of wasting money on potions.

Comment: Just wiped at floor 13. He had 31 attack, 7 defense, 100 HP. I had the second highest level weapon, which was 14 dmg. My shield was second highest, 10 defense, and HP was like 160ish, I don't fully remember. I am not sure how to beat this guy... Some levels, you get no money at all

Comment: It's designed so it cannot be beaten. According to the wiki, Floors 23/24 are designed not to be beatable, and after that (should you manage to beat them somehow) the levels are auto generated into infinity. Source: http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=super_rpg

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't figure out how to get past 24.

I'm thinking that it's just not statistically possible.

Here's my order (note, sometimes with the very slight variations in stats, this can fail)

1. Wooden sword
2. Copper Shield
3. Iron Sword       -- potion up to >5 hp
4. Silver Shield    -- potion up to >9 hp
5. Health Pend (to 15)  -- potion up to >13 hp
6. Diamond Sword    -- potion up to >10 hp
7. Nothing      -- potion up to >13 hp
8. Shield of El Cid, Health Pendants up to 35, -- potion up to > 29 hp
9. Nothing      -- potion up to >31 hp
10. Shield of Achilles (with this gear, This level can not hurt you at all)
11. Vorpal Sword    -- potion up to >27 hp
12. Nothing     (with this gear, this level can not hurt you at all)
13. Wynebgwrthucher (with this gear, this level can not hurt you at all)
14. Morgul-Blade, Health Pendants as high as you can go (145+)
    (The dragon has some slight varaition in his stats, if you get a high attack of 31 and a high defense of 8 or 9, you're done. Sorry)
15. Excalibur    (with this gear, this level can not hurt you)
16. Aegis       -- potion up to >37 hp
17. nothing     -- potion up to >109 hp
18. Health Crystal up to 195+ -- potion up to >181 hp
19. Health Crystal up to 255+ -- potion up to >253 hp
20. Health Crystal up to 335+ -- ption up to >325 hp
21. Mjolnir     -- potion up to >200 hp
    (at this point, Mjolnir and Aegis are the best items possible. I don't know if there are new items after 25 or not.)
22. nothing     -- potion up to >234 hp
23. nothing     -- potion up to >272 hp
24. nothing     -- potion up to >306
    (after this, it seems to be mathematically not possible...)
25. nothing     -- somehow have over 684 hp
26. ?? mystery

If anyone can figure out how to get further, I'd love to see it. :D

Comment: I got to level 15 following the guide above, and made it to level 25 just buying all the health upgrades and attack weapons i could get, no shields after Aegis.

Comment: This guide works a treat, although there are randomizations, so it may take a few turns to get past the dragon, etc.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that you somehow need to have *at least* 1030 coins when you reach Floor 13 for this system to work.

Comment: From what I can gather, it all basically comes down to Floor 12: If you get three chests, you might beat the dragon, if you get two or more bombs, forget about it: You'll never have enough energy. Luck, basically. No matter how you do on the preceding levels, it all comes down to that.

Comment: According to the wiki, Floors 23/24 are designed not to be beatable, and after that (should you manage to beat them somehow) the levels are auto generated into infinity. Source: http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=super_rpg

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt You should put this comment as an answer

Answer (score 7):

I can repeatedly get to the dragon, just to fail there with this strategy:

Be warned, the monsters have randomized stats. This strategy can randomly fail you.
(+ means and)

0: Wooden sword
1: Copper Shield
2: Iron Sword (pot if below or at 4 HP)
3: Health pot + Silver shield  to 9 HP min
4: pot +15 maxHP
5: Diamond Sword + pot + 20 maxHP
6: pot to nearlyfull (meaning don't waste money) , 35-40 maxHP
7: Shield of El Cid + Pot, 35 HP necessary.
8: pot to nearly full,  60-65 maxHP
9: pot to nearly full
10:Vorpal Sword + pots  (Vorpal is necessary for floor 12's bombs)
11: pots
12: Morgul-Blade, Ancile, rest in maxHP
13: Pray you get three chests, into maxHP
14: No strategy yet past this.

You can probably skip the Excalibur. And the Aegis?

Past fourteen, the monsters get insanely strong (floor 21 monsters have 94 ATK), and ATK equipment starts costing 1k, 1,5k and 2k, DEF equipment stagnates at the Aegis, while they just drop a few hundred total at best. Not sure if this can be beaten.
I got 40k candies for beating the dragon.

Comment: This is working pretty well for me.  I can't always get the Morgul blade or Ancile by the dragon, however. I have come very close to killing him twice (once with both, once with Morgul, El Cid, and a ton of health since I was just short of being able to buy ancile).

Comment: I have tried skipping all of the post-dragon weapons until Mjollnir, but I can't quite make it.  Buying Gungir doesn't extended my stay in the dungeon very often, either.

Answer (score 6):

I got to floor 22 using the guide. You can skip excalibur and the aegis. Aegis only gives you 2 more def. Problem is I never saw a better shield than the Aegis.
Eventually you'll get mjolnir as a weapon option (2k). I didnt get a chance to grab it because I was an idiot and bought excalibur after I'd passed it up 3 or 4 times.
I basically just funneled money in to max hp (got up to around 470).

got 40k candies as a reward.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of easy to go up to lvl 13 but I've found no way around him so far. Prolly need a lot of boxes and luck.

For early levels try shield>sword>sword>shield+pendant
Make sure you have the 100 coin sword and 25 hp by level 7

Comment: sword > sword in the first 2 levels actually works better. If you get lucky on the first round, you only take 2-3 dmg. And second round sword one shots everything.