# How do I beat the level 10 candy arcade game in hard mode?

Tags: candy-box-2

I unlocked hard mode in the Super RPG game by beating level 20 or so in the regular game. Now when I play it, all of the enemies are harder and I can't get past level 4. Is there any strategy for getting farther than that?

Comment: Impressive. I get usually stuck around level 13.

Comment: Whoops, I voted to close this as [a duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137115/), but I just realized you are asking about hard mode specifically.