# Does Super RPG minigame help, or is it just for fun?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've seen the [guide to completing the minigame](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137115/how-to-beat-the-10-candy-arcade-game-super-rpg), but I was wondering whether it earned anything for the character outside of the minigame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You earn candy for the first time when reaching any floor, but none if you reach it again, and you only get more if you beat your record.

For example: If you finished on floor 7, you will receive 100 candies, but if you reach up to floor 7 again, you will get nothing.

[Source](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=the_third_house&s[]=super&s[]=rpg)